# Display item of same category from array list in html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a array that hold the list of category and its details.
I am trying to display all the content of the same category.

For example, when the user click on the "Wholesome fun for the family" button it will then display all the data that is under the category of "Wholesome fun for the family".

How can I go about doing it?

HTML

```
<body>

<!-------------------------------------------------------- Home Page - List of activity category -------------------------------------------------------->
<nav class='current'>
    <h1>FUNpedia</h1>
    <a class='button' id="goto-new-note">New</a>
</nav>
<article id="home" class="current">
    <section>
        <ul class="list" id="home-category-list">
        </ul>
    </section>
</article>


<!-------------------------------------------- Selected Activity Page - List of activities within the category -------------------------------------------->
<nav class='next'>
    <!-- <a class='button backTo' id="goto-home">Back</a> -->
    <a id="goto-home" style="margin-top:10px;"><img src="img/backBtn.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
    <h1>Attractions</h1>
</nav>

<article id="category-view" class="next">
    <section>
        <ul class='list'>
            <li class='comp'>
                <!-- <h3 class='category-title'></h3>
                <p class='category-content'></p> -->
                <aside>
                <img title='Imagine Dragons' src="../images/music/Imagine Dragons.png" height="80px">
                </aside>
            <div>
                <h3 class='category-title'></h3>
                <h4 class='category-categoryName'></h4>
                <p class='category-content'></p>
            </div>
                <aside>
                <span class='show-detail'></span>
                </aside>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</article>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------- Array of category and detail ----------------------------------------------------------- */
    var category = [
        {
            categoryName: "Wholesome fun for the family",
            imageName: "attraction.jpg",
            content: "Number 1"
        },
        {
            categoryName: "Wholesome fun for the family",
            imageName: "attraction.jpg",
            content: "Number 2"
        },
        {
            categoryName: "Adventure for the family",
            imageName: "themePark.jpg",
            content: "Hihihihi"
        },
        {
            categoryName: "For the young and curious",
            imageName: "youngExplorer.jpg",
            content: "Hihihihi"
        },
        {
            categoryName: "A city of greenery",
            imageName: "parkNgarden.jpg",
            content: "Hihihihi"
        },
        {
            categoryName: "Get ready to experience explosive sporting action",
            imageName: "extremeSG.jpg",
            content: "Hihihihi"
        },
        {
            categoryName: "Fun in the water",
            imageName: "wetAdventure.jpg",
            content: "Hihihihi"
        }
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
        listNode(i);
    }

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------- Display the list of category ----------------------------------------------------------- */
    function listNode(id) {
        $("#home-category-list").append("<li class='nav' data-id='" + id + "'>" +
                                    "<img src=img/" + category[id].imageName + ">" +
                                    "</li>");
    }

    /* -------------------------------------------------- Show the list of activities within the category -------------------------------------------------- */
    $("#home-category-list").on("singletap", "li", function() {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        listActivities(id);
    });

    function listActivities(id) {
        $("#category-view").data("id", id);

        $("#category-view .category-title").text(category[id].categoryName);
        $("#category-view .category-content").html(category[id].content);
        $("#category-view .category-categoryName").html(category[id].categoryName);

        $.UIGoToArticle("#category-view");
    }
```

Comment: You should take care of array structure when creating the array in javascript. It will be easy if category names would be keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/quqale/3/edit)** *(updated)*

I changed a lot of your HTML for clarity purpose. I'm not sure it's the result you want but I'm pretty sure you will figure it all out from here.

The javascript magic:

```
var category = [...];

//generate a category list without repeated categories
function newCategoryList(){
  var categoryList = [];
  for(var a=0; a<category.length; a++){
    var unique = true;
    for(var b=0; b<categoryList.length; b++){
      if(category[a].categoryName == categoryList[b].name) unique = false;    
    }
    if(unique) categoryList.push({
      name: category[a].categoryName,
      img: category[a].imageName
    });
  }
  return categoryList;
}

//add category to home list
function listCategories(id) {
  $('#home-category-list').append('<li class="nav" data-id="'+id+'"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/&text='+categoryList[id].img+'"/>'+categoryList[id].name+'</li>');
}

//list all activities in the respective category
function listActivities(id){
  $('#home-activity-list').html('');
  var cat = categoryList[id];
  for(var a=0; a<category.length; a++){
    if(category[a].categoryName == cat.name){
      newActivity(a);
    }
  }
}


//add new Activity to the list
function newActivity(id){  
  var img = $('<img src="http://placehold.it/150x50/&text='+category[id].imageName+'">');
  var title = $('<h3>'+category[id].categoryName+'</h3>');
  var content = $('<p>'+category[id].content+'</p>');
  var li = $('<li>').append(img, title, content).appendTo($('#home-activity-list'));
}

//generate the list of categories  
var categoryList = newCategoryList();

//list all categories
$.each(categoryList, listCategories);

//attach category click event
$("#home-category-list").on("click singletap", "li", function(){
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  listActivities(id);
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
});

//populate the Activity list
newActivity(0);
```

Comment: Thanks your help.
Also, is it possible to save also the imageName into the categoryList so that at the home-category-list I can display the image of the category instead of the word?

I have been trying to push the categoryName and imageName into the categoryList, but when I display it in the home-category-list it shows all the categoryName and imageName one after the other. Instead of showing only the imageName.

Comment: I updated the answer so it displays the category image in the categoryList. Also added a animated scroll and some style ... enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Change `singletap` event to `click` event. I do that and now the category information appears ([JSFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/pdv89r1t/2/)).

This is the code I use to test (I commented `$.UIGoToArticle("#category-view")` because I don't have a reference to UIGoToArticle):

```
var category = [
      {
          categoryName: "Wholesome fun for the family",
          imageName: "attraction.jpg",
          content: "Number 1"
      },
      {
          categoryName: "Wholesome fun for the family",
          imageName: "attraction.jpg",
          content: "Number 2"
      },
      {
          categoryName: "Adventure for the family",
          imageName: "themePark.jpg",
          content: "Hihihihi"
      },
      {
          categoryName: "For the young and curious",
          imageName: "youngExplorer.jpg",
          content: "Hihihihi"
      },
      {
          categoryName: "A city of greenery",
          imageName: "parkNgarden.jpg",
          content: "Hihihihi"
      },
      {
          categoryName: "Get ready to experience explosive sporting action",
          imageName: "extremeSG.jpg",
          content: "Hihihihi"
      },
      {
          categoryName: "Fun in the water",
          imageName: "wetAdventure.jpg",
          content: "Hihihihi"
      }
  ];



  $( document ).ready(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
          listNode(i);
      }


      $("#home-category-list").on("click", "li", function() {
          var id = $(this).data("id");
          listActivities(id);
      });
  });

  function listNode(id) {
      $("#home-category-list").append("<li class='nav' data-id='" + id + "'>" + "<img src=img/" + category[id].imageName + ">" + "</li>");
  }



  function listActivities(id) {
      $("#category-view").data("id", id);
      var aux = $("#category-view .category-title");
      $("#category-view .category-title").text(category[id].categoryName);
      $("#category-view .category-content").html(category[id].content);
      $("#category-view .category-categoryName").html(category[id].categoryName);

      //$.UIGoToArticle("#category-view");
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

To display the content of all the categories with same name you need to do something like this ([JSFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/pdv89r1t/4/)):

```
function listActivities(id) {
    $("#category-view").data("id", id);
    var aux = $("#category-view .category-title");
    $("#category-view .category-title").text(category[id].categoryName);


    $("#category-view .category-content").empty();

    var selectedName = category[id].categoryName;

    $.each(category, function()
    {
        if(this.categoryName == selectedName)
          $("#category-view .category-content").append(this.content);
    });

    $("#category-view .category-categoryName").html(category[id].categoryName);

    //$.UIGoToArticle("#category-view");
}
```

The `.html()` replace the HTML element inner content, so in this case you need to use `.append()` or `.attach()` to append the categories content one by one, or join all in a variable and then do something like `.html(variable )`.

Comment: But if there is two item in the same category (e.g. Wholesome fun for the family), when I click on the "Wholesome fun for the family" can I display 2 item in the page? Is it possible to achieve that?

I tried yours when I clicked on "Wholesome fun for the family" it only shows the item content of Number 1. I wanted it to show the content of Number 1 and Number 2 as it is in the same category.

Comment: If you want to display both numbers so you need to do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pdv89r1t/3/): http://jsfiddle.net/pdv89r1t/3/ . If you use `.html()` the inner code of the HTML element is replaced. For join two things in the HTML element you need to append/attach one by one or join both in a variable and then use `.html()` with that variable